# Python - open() isn't working

Tags: python, discord

```
#BLACKLIST PROFILE CREATION COMMAND
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def blacklist(ctx, removeoradd, user: discord.Member, *, reason):
    if ctx.message.author.id == developerID:
        if removeoradd == "add":
            case_id = "BL-" + id_generator(10, "1234567890")

            blacklist_template = "{\"" + user.id + "\": {\"userid\": \"" + user.id + "\", \"reason\": \"" + reason + "\", \"banned_by\": \"" + ctx.message.author.id + "\", \"case_id\": \"" + case_id + "\", \"active\": \"True\"}}"

#           with open("C:/Blacklisted/{}.json".format(ctx.message.author.id), "w") as json_file:
#               json.dump(blacklist_template, json_file)
            blacklist = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Blacklisted/{}.json".format(ctx.message.author.id)), "x")

            blacklist.write("{}".format(blacklist_template))

            blacklist.close()

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Admin Control", description="Blacklisted:\n``{}/{}``".format(user.name, user.id))
            embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=reason)
            embed.add_field(name="Case ID", value=case_id)
            embed.set_footer(text="v" + version + " | " + localtime)
            await bot.say(embed=embed)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="You can no longer create a profile.", description="If you think this is a mistake do {}appeal <reason>".format(prefix))
            embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=reason)
            embed.add_field(name="Case ID", value=case_id)
            embed.set_footer(text="v" + version + " | " + localtime)
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, embed=embed)

        elif removeoradd == "remove":
            pass
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="An error occured", description="Invalid argument.\nInsert ``add`` or ``remove``.", color=0xc20000)
            await bot.say(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="An error occured", description="No permission.\nYou need to be a verified developer to do this.", color=0xc20000)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

```
  File "run.py", line 126, in blacklist
blacklist = open(os.path.expanduser("/Blacklisted/{}.json".format(ctx.message.author.id)), "x")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Blacklisted/182288858782629888.json'
```

so basically im trying to create a file with the blacklist_template contents. I thought that when you use the "w" mode, it creates a new file for you. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The traceback doesn't match your code.

Comment: i removed the ~ by accident sorry

Comment: You're right about the creation of the **FILE** but it does not create directories. This error means that you don't have a `Blacklisted/` directory in your root `/` (or in your home if the error should show `~/Blacklisted...`)

Comment: The directory exists.

Comment: Python is looking at `/Blacklisted/`, a directory in the root of the filesystem, not a directory in your home directory. As Ignacio said, your traceback doesn't match your code. Look closely at the error message: `blacklist = open(os.path.expanduser("/Blacklisted/{}.json"...` There is no `~` for `expanduser()` to expand.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I got this now.